# How to resolve the error of type- [NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, box-api

I just tried to integrate my xcode project with box account, for creating a new folder  following the steps in "https://github.com/box/box-ios-sdk".

Initially completed the authentication process following the link, "http://developers.box.com/authentication-in-your-ios-app/".

Build succeeded and gets the box account authentication process and gets the required name for creating a new folder. Then I experienced the following

```
Error- {Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'}
```

Code for creating new folder:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad  {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.title = @"Create Folder";
   [self.textView becomeFirstResponder];  
}



- (IBAction)gotobutton:(id)sender {  

    [Box createFolderWithName:self.textView.text parentFolderID:[BoxID numberWithInt:0] share:NO callbacks:^(id<BoxOperationCallbacks> on) 

   {
        on.after(^(BoxCallbackResponse response) 

      {
            if (response == BoxCallbackResponseSuccessful) 

           {
                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success"  
                message:@"Folder created." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"       
                otherButtonTitles:nil] ;   
                [alertView show];
           } 

            else 

            {
                [BoxErrorHandler presentErrorAlertViewForResponse:response];
            }

        });

    }];
}
```

How to get out of the error, do any one experience this before?
Help please!!!

Comment: You could add a breakpoint (or an `NSLog`) just before `[Box createFolderWithName:...` and ensure that `self.textView.text` is not `nil` (probably their sdk builds an `NSURL` with that string using it as a path).

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint and examine the stack.

Comment: I have breakpoints in necessary places,and it works fine till the last step of connecting to the box account.Added NSLog and [self.textview.text] = "name of the folder given" while its running, and got exception as,
upload[1114:3d0f]***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',reason:'***-[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
***First throw call stack:
(0x1a90012 0x1585e7e 0x1a8fdeb 0xf9c9b1 0xf9c93b 0x5426e 0x1ca86 0x16f853f 0x170a014 0x16fa418 0x16fa2a6 0x16fb280 0x16fb450 0x9a4b4e12 0x9a49ccca)libc++abi.dylib:terminate called throwing exception

Comment: There is no such statement,[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: in my file,then what is the reason of such occurrence error???  And i experience the same error for both creating a new folder and for upload a file to my box account... Why thats happening so???

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to copy the core data from the Box framework.
Go under your target in Xcode, then go to the "*Build Phases*" tab and in the "*Run Script*" add something like the following:
(just change the source directory to where you have placed the framework in your project)

```
cp -fr ./Box.framework/Resources/BoxCoreDataStore.momd "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH}/BoxCoreDataStore.momd"
```